# Rust: Mutate an Option field whose wrapped value doesnt implement the Copy trait

Tags: rust

I have a `Message` struct which have a field I want to modify when calling a method on it.

This `Message` struct have an `attachments` field, which is an `Option<Vec<Attachment>>`.

My goal is to be able to call a method on `Message` to push an `Attachment` object to the `attachments` `Vec`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Message {
    /// The verified sender email address
    #[serde(rename = "FromEmail")]
    pub from_email: String,
    /// The name of the sender
    #[serde(rename = "FromName")]
    pub from_name: String,
    /// The subject of the email
    #[serde(rename = "Subject")]
    pub subject: Option<String>,
    /// The raw text content of the email
    #[serde(rename = "Text-part")]
    pub text_part: String,
    /// The HTML content of the email
    #[serde(rename = "Html-part")]
    pub html_part: Option<String>,
    #[serde(rename = "Recipients")]
    pub recipients: Vec<Recipient>,
    #[serde(rename = "Attachments")]
    pub attachments: Option<Vec<Attachment>>,
    #[serde(rename = "Inline_attachments")]
    pub inline_attachments: Option<Vec<InlineAttachments>>,
}
```

The following is my current implementation on the method that will push `Attachment` objects to the `Option<Vec<Attachment>>`:

```rust
    pub fn attach(&mut self, attachment: Attachment) {
        // if theres no attachments already
        // initialize the attachments vector
        if self.attachments.is_none() {
            let mut attachments = Vec::new();

            attachments.push(attachment);
            self.attachments = Some(attachments);
        } else {
            // Where this is invalid as theres no `clone` for `Option<Vec<Attachment>>`

            let attachments = self.attachments.clone();

            attachments.push(attachment);
        }
    }
```

This is the implementation for the `Attachment` `struct`:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

/// An email attachment
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Attachment {
  #[serde(rename = "Content-type")]
  pub content_type: String,
  #[serde(rename = "Filename")]
  pub filename: String,
  pub content: String,
}
```

The issue is on the `else` block, where the `attachents` `Option` field is unwrapped, then an `attachment` object is pushed to the `Vec`.

The problem is that `Attachment` is unable to implement the `Copy` trait.

Which is the correct approach for scenarios like this in Rust?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vec::new() does not do any buffer allocation, so you might just get rid of the Option wrapper if you can get serde to play nicely with the new type.

Answer (score 6):

`Option` has a wide variety of helper methods which can help here.  You basically want to mutate the `Vec` that's already there if there is one, and if not, create one and mutate it.  You can do that with `Option::get_or_insert_with`, which returns a `&mut Vec<Attachment>`.  With that, you can push the item onto the end.  A minimal compilable example looks like this:

```
pub struct Message {
    pub attachments: Option<Vec<Attachment>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Attachment {
    pub content_type: String,
    pub filename: String,
    pub content: String,
}

impl Message {
    pub fn attach(&mut self, attachment: Attachment) {
        self.attachments
            .get_or_insert_with(Vec::new)
            .push(attachment);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Message { attachments: None };
    let a = Attachment {
        content_type: "application/json".into(),
        filename: "foo.json".into(),
        content: "{}".into(),
    };
    m.attach(a);
    assert_eq!(m.attachments.unwrap()[0].content, "{}");
}
```

If you're using `is_some` or `is_none` (or, for `Result`, `is_ok` or `is_err`) in an if-else situation, that's usually an indication that you may want to rethink what you're doing, since that's not usually very idiomatic in Rust.  Oftentimes, there's a helper method that does what you want in a simpler, easier to use way.

Comment: This reply is just awesome! Thanks so much bk2204!